# ORACLE SQL: only show specific value if appears more than once

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table that has two columns...

```
LN    |   SRCREF
LN-1  |  LN/123456
LN-1  |  LN/789012
LN-2  |  LN/123456
LN-2  |  LN/098765
LN-3  |  LN/123456
LN-3  |  LN/789012
LN-3  |  LN/432109
```

And I want to return something like this...

```
LN    |    SRCREF
LN-1  |  LN/123456
LN-1  |  LN/789012
LN-2  |  LN/098765
LN-3  |  LN/432109
```

So in other words I only want to return the SRCREF once but in a priority order so I see all those that have LN-1s then those that don't have LN-1s but LN-2s then finally those that just have LN-3s.

I hope that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by SRCREF. This means that you only have each value SRCREF once in your results.

Then, you can use an *aggregate function* to get one specific value from LN to go with that SRCREF value. In this case, I'm using `min` which returns the lowest value. So you get the lowest LN value that goes with each SRCREF value.

Finally, I'm using `order by` to sort by that lowest value.

```
select
  min(LN) as first,
  SRCREF 
from
  YourTable t
group by
  SRCREF 
order by
  min(LN)
```

Note that in this case you might get odd results, because the first column is a character field. That means that its contents are compared alphabetically. This means that L-10 will come before L-2. There are other ways to solve that, but I don't know if it's going to be an issue for you.

Comment: This works perfectly, because the codes go from LN-1 to LN-9 then go alphabetical, so thanks.